# TypeError: 'open' object does not support indexing, but can still be iterated over. How to get the first n results of an Open object?

Tags: python

I can iterate over an Open object using this code

```
with jsonl.open("train.dataset", gzip = True) as train_file:
    for entry in train_file:
        print(entry["summary"], entry["text"])
```

But say that I only want the first 10 results. This code

```
with jsonl.open("train.dataset", gzip = True) as train_file:
    for i in range(0, 10):
        print(train_file[i]["summary"], train_file[i]["text"])
```

results in

> TypeError: 'open' object does not support indexing

If an object can be iterated over, why can't it support indexing to directly access parts. And is there an alternative way to get data at a particular index, and/or only retrieve the first n results?

Comment: You need to do something like : `train_file[i]["summary"]` in place of `entry["summary"]`

Comment: what's `jsonl`?  classes are free to implement the `__iter__` method and not `__getitem__`.  this would give the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: @pault @ arajshree sorry that was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 now `entry` is not defined in that scope.

Comment: fixed again , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *train_file* is a `list`, you can use a slice:

```py
with jsonl.open("train.dataset", gzip=True) as train_file:
    for entry in train_file[0:10]:
        print(entry["summary"], entry["text"])
```

If *train_file* is an iterable, you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```py
import itertools

with jsonl.open("train.dataset", gzip=True) as train_file:
    for entry in itertools.islice(train_file, 10):
        print(entry["summary"], entry["text"])
```